# Working with two contact forms on one site

Tags: php

I've got 2 contact forms on a site. One is for simple contact-us and the other is for a registration. I've got them pointing to two different php and js files. The contact-us form is working, but I can't get the registration form to work. Here's the php:

```
<?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
  empty($_POST['email'])        ||
  empty($_POST['phoneNumber']) ||
  empty($_POST['childFirstName']) ||
  empty($_POST['childLastName'])  ||
  empty($_POST['childAge']) ||
!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
  }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
$message = $_POST['childFirstName'];
$message = $_POST['childLastName'];
$message = $_POST['childAge'];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'lloyd.leeiv@yahoo.com';
$email_subject = "Contact form submitted by:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. \n\n".
              " Here are the details:\n \n Parent/Guardian Name: $name \n ".
              "Email: $email_address \n Phone: $phoneNumber \n Child's Name: $childFirstName $childLastName \n Age: $childAge";
$headers = "From: JNGSO@jngso.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

And the HTML:

```
 <form name="sentMessage" class="well" id="contactForm"  novalidate>
                    <p>Parent/Guardian Name</p>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                                placeholder="Parent/Guardian Name" id="name" required
                                data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name" />
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <p>Email Address</p>    
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" 
                                id="email" required
                                data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email" />
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <p>Phone Number</p>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" 
                                id="phoneNumber" required
                                data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number" />
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <p>Child's First Name</p>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Child's First Name" 
                                id="childFirstName" required
                                data-validation-required-message="Please enter your child's first name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>Child's Last Name</p>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Child's Last Name" 
                                id="text" required
                                data-validation-required-message="Please enter your child's last name" />
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <p>Child's Age</p>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Child's Age" 
                                id="number" required
                                data-validation-required-message="Please enter your child's age" />
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <p>Boy or Girl?</p>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="boyGirl" id="boy" value="Boy"> Boy
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="boyGirl" id="girl" value="Girl"> Girl
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="success"> </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right">Send</button><br />
                </form>
```

I've got the proper script links on the page (changed the name to point to the correct js file) and in the js file I'm pointing to the correct php url. Like I said, it works with the contact-us form but not this one. I can't figure out what I'm missing!

Comment: Also, both forms are pointing to the same email address

Comment: None of your inputs have name attributes, only `name="boyGirl"` and `type="number"` but that isn't even part of your code for POSTs.

Comment: You might want to use the method and action attributes for the form tag.

Comment: If any of the comments didn't help, then post your JS. If you're not using `$.post` in Ajax, then as stated by @Mex - Forms defaults to GET, unless given a method, being POST.

Comment: Ok, well I am moving on. `@` me if you need something. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I threw this question up in desperation (because I'm new to php and I didn't think I could solve it). After carefully examining it, it's actually pretty simple! doh!

I just had to make sure all of the id's were labeled, all of the var were accounted for and everything matched up in my php. For example, you can see above I have:

```
....
$message = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
$message = $_POST['childFirstName'];
$message = $_POST['childLastName'];
$message = $_POST['childAge'];
....
```

in my php where I should have each of those labeled differen't (not each one as `$message`).

I'm sorry if this wasted anyone's time, but hopefully someone can find this useful.